# Linear Functional - Basis change

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Having a trouble understanding what you have to do in case you have a "simple" linear functional. The basis change and stuff for Quadratic and Bilinear forms are everywhere in every book, but there is not even a starting part for the linear functionals and their basis change. The question I have is of the style :

Given the functional $f[x,  y, z]^T = 3x - 2y + z$ in $\mathbb R^3$. Write the functional with respect to the coordinates of the basis : $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ where $v_1 = [1,1,0]^T$, $v_2 = [0,2,1]^T$, $v_3 = [-2,1,1]^T$.

Now, the thought I had about this is to express the functional values of the ordinary basis $f(e_1),f(e_2),f(e_3)$ with respect to constants $a_{ij}$ and $e_i$. After that, I'd go on by expressing the vectors of the new basis with respect to $b_{ij}$ and $e_i$, to find the $b_{ij}$ and thus the matrix of the functional with respect to the "new" basis. Is that method correct ? I would really appreciate a hint or someone going through a complete solution of the given problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to find the matrix of a linear transformation with respect to a new basis?

Comment: This is part of what I am asking. I think it's the same thing, expressing stuff as I said ?

Comment: I'm trying to see if you already knew the answer without realizing it, since this topic is usually covered well before a discussion of bilinear forms.

Comment: Well, I think that it should be the way I said it, by expressing each coordinate of the basis vectors, but not sure about it + I am studying for the end term exam which is the following week so I am trying to find books and sources to confirm every solution I bring down so I am in a correct way of understanding things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the matrix representation with respect to the new basis, we note that
$$
f(a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + a_3 v_3) =\\
a_1f(v_1) + a_2f(v_2) + a_3f(v_3) = \\
a_1 - 3a_2 - 7a_3
$$
I would say that this equation constitutes an answer to the question as stated.

We can say moreover that the matrix of the linear functional with respect to this new basis is $\pmatrix{1&-3&-7}$.

Comment: So, the form of the linear functional with respect to the coordinates of the new basis is : $f([x',y',z']^T) = x' - 3y' - 7z'$ ?

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos yes, that's right.

Comment: Okay, got it now. Thanks a lot mate for the fast response and cooperation !